# VBA Row Counting Across Multiple Sheets with Overflow Error

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to get the message box to display the row counts for my entire workbook (3 Sheets). It will run the first one and then on the second I keep getting an Overflow error. Any tips on how to update this so it will run through?

```
Sub StockAnalysis()
Dim total As Double

Dim rowIndex As Long
Dim change As Double
Dim columnIndex As Integer
Dim start As Long
Dim rowCount As Long
Dim percentChange As Double
Dim days As Integer
Dim dailyChange As Single
Dim averageChange As Double
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In Worksheets
    
columnIndex = 0
total = o
change = 0
start = 2
dailyChange = 0
    
ws.Range("I1").Value = "Ticker"
ws.Range("J1").Value = "Yearly Change"
ws.Range("K1").Value = "Percent Change"
ws.Range("L1").Value = "Total Stock Volume"
ws.Range("P1").Value = "Ticker"
ws.Range("Q1").Value = "Value"
ws.Range("O2").Value = "Greatest % Increase"
ws.Range("O3").Value = "Greatest % Decrease"
ws.Range("O4").Value = "Greatest Total Volume"

rowCount = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
MsgBox (rowCount)
    
Next ws

End Sub
```

I was expecting to get the counts for the rows in all 3 of my sheets, but on the second message box pop up I get an overflow error.

Comment: Get no error with this code on a empty sheet.

Comment: To get the `rowCount` don't you want to move to the last non-empty row by using `End(xlDown)`?

Comment: Be careful to fully [qualify your references](https://riptutorial.com/excel-vba/example/5110/qualifying-references) because `ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row` references the `Cells` on `ws`, but the `Rows.Count` is from the currently active sheet - which may not be `ws`.